# Problems with User and Topic Seed Data with Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed, faker

I am new to programming, and have been trying to make some seed data using Faker for a simple bookmark app. Topics belong to users, and bookmarks belong to topics, so I'm trying to make seed data with topics that have user_ids. Originally, I just put user.sample, but I need to have the user_id of the user who owns the topic, and the bookmark needs the topic_id of the topic it belongs to. You can see below one of my efforts here. How do you go about doing this?  Here is my seed data:

```
require 'faker'

    #create users
    10.times do 
      user = User.new(
        name: Faker::Name.name,
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        password: 'helloworld'
      )
      user.save!  
    end
    users=User.all

    # create bookmarks
    30.times do 
        Bookmark.create(
        topic_id: topic.sample,
        url: Faker::Internet.url
        )
      end
      bookmarks = Bookmark.all

    # create topics
    10.times do
      Topic.create(
        name: Faker::Name.name,
        user_id: user.sample
      )
    end
    topics= Topic.all

    #create admin
    admin = User.new(
      name: 'admin',
      email: 'admin@example.com',
      password: 'helloworld'
    )
    admin.save

    puts 'Seed Finished'
    puts "#{users.count} users created"
    puts "#{topics.count} topics created"
    puts "#{bookmarks.count} bookmarks created"
```

Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150118002825) do

  create_table "bookmarks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "likes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "bookmark_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

and here are my models:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookmarks

end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  has_many :topics

end
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :topics
  has_many :likes

end
```

Comment: A very good question. I voted it up. I'm trying to figure out something similar but I get errors. Are you getting errors Eric? What is happening when you do this $ bundle exec rake db:seed ? I am using activerecord-sinatra but it's just rake tasks on active_record gem so not much different from Rails. I did not have to do any saves the first time I had faker seeding the db. It just worked. Now I'm having an issue with it. I don't know what yet. UsersCreate.create([5 seeds of data]) gives me an unrecognized token "{" and I did things pretty much like you have. see railscasts on this. It's free.

Comment: If you want to see what I have it's at https://github.com/DouglasAllen/my_active_record_sinatra